# Select from table

Tags: sql, postgresql

select records from table using like for loop in postgres 
where user given value less than particular column value then stop loop 
else select next record based on remaining value

ex:

```
NO:   value:   
inv1 5
inv2 20
inv3 30
```

user given value 23 means

No:  value:   selectedvalue

```
inv1  5      5
inv2  20     18
```

Comment: I see that you select the first records, but not the third one, because 30 > 23. But where does the other 5 and the 18 come from in your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with temp as (

SELECT value,number1  FROM (SELECT  number1, sum(value) OVER
(ORDER BY number1 ) 
 t
FROM table as ta

) a where   8+value > t )

select value,number1 from temp

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a cumulative sum and some additional logic:

```
select t.*,
       (case when cume_value < 23 then value
             else cume_value - value
        end)
from (select t.*,
             sum(value) over (order by ??) as cume_value
      from t
     ) t
where cume_value < 23;
```

The `??` represents the column you are using for ordering the rows in the table.  SQL tables represent unordered sets so you need an ordering column.  In your case, this might be `value`.

Comment: i used this query if the sum(value) is greater than the given value means it cannot take that row